# Stop processes if pgsql2shp/shp2pgsql fails

Tags: postgresql, error, shp2pgsql, pgsql2shp

I have a process where data is extracted from PostgreSQL (PostGIS) to shapefiles. The data is used as input creating new data (shapefiles) through a program outside PostgreSQL.
The new data is then uploaded to the same PostgreSQL-database.

I am using `pgsql2shp` and `shp2pgsql` for extracting and uploading, respectively.

Currently, the process works fine. However when I introduce errors to the `pgsql2shp` command, the program doesn't stop the next commands.
This is expected, as according to the [pgsql2shp/shp2pgsql cheat-sheet](http://www.bostongis.com/pgsql2shp_shp2pgsql_quickguide_20.bqg) the default behaviour is to continue.

In the example below, I have created a query for the point- and polygon-data, which return empty results.
The logfile (simplified):

```bash
MSG - getting shapefile_points.shp
INFO - Initializing...
INFO - ERROR: Could not determine table metadata (empty table)
MSG - getting shapefile_polygons.shp
INFO - Initializing...
INFO - ERROR: Could not determine table metadata (empty table)
MSG - getting shapefile_lines.shp 
INFO - Initializing...
INFO - Done (postgis major version: 3).
Output shape: PolyLine
Dumping: X
INFO - X
INFO - X
INFO - X
INFO - X
INFO - X
...
```

I have tried passing the option `--exit-on-error` to pgsql2shp as such:

`pgsql2shp --exit-on-error -k -f $input_dir/shapefile_points.shp  -g geom $PGDATABASE "select * from ... where ..."`

and get the following error:

```bash
MSG - getting shapefile_points.shp
INFO - pgsql2shp: illegal option -- -
RELEASE: 3.0.0 (r17983)
USAGE: pgsql2shp [<options>] <database> [<schema>.]<table>
       pgsql2shp [<options>] <database> <query>
...
```

Comment: you can't just make up new options. I don't think that `pgsql2shp` can do what you want, try `ogr2ogr` instead

Comment: I dont know how official it is, but the [cheatsheet](http://www.bostongis.com/pgsql2shp_shp2pgsql_quickguide_20.bqg) has the option as such: `-e, --exit-on-error      exit on error, default is to continue`
( i have also tried -e)

Comment: that's a `psql` option not `pgsql2shp`